# Objective C - Hiding multiple UI elements

Tags: objective-c, hide, element

So I have an application made from 2 view controllers, one controller is a main screen where all the UI elements are displayed, the other controller handles what UI elements are on the main controller.

Currently I have lots of statements like to hide / show certain elements depending on what the user wants to display.

```
label.hidden = TRUE;
label2.hidden = TRUE;
label3.hidden = FALSE;
```

Obviously the actual application is a lot larger than this and there are a lot more statements.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

I was thinking a seperate UIView for each possible main screen variation. Then display a UIView depending on what elements are to be displayed. Would this be correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should even create multiple viewControllers.

Comment: Hmm, well this way there would be about 10 view controllers which seems a large amount for what each UIView would do.

Comment: No, this is overkill, especially if all of the methods are the same. You can call different views from one controller.

Answer (score 0):

A parent UIView as you suggest is probably the best option in terms of keeping the hierarchy obvious and editable in Interface Builder (or the Xcode 4 analogue thereof).

An alternative would be to put all the views you want to toggle into an array just once, and perform:

```
[arrayOfViews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setHidden:)
              withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

Which has the effect of hiding every single view in the array.

In my apps I tend to have some groups of views that I can move or hide/show together, in which case I collect them in a single parent view, some that move or hide/show alone, in which case I obviously treat them singly, and some that are so different from one orientation to the other that I keep alternates as you suggest.

Straying slightly from the topic, if you're doing distinct views for different orientations you might be better implementing something like:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                 duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation))
    {
        portraitView.alpha = 1.0f;
        landscapeView.alpha = 0.0f;
    }
    else
    {
        portraitView.alpha = 0.0f;
        landscapeView.alpha = 1.0f;
    }
}
```

Which will give a sort of cross-fade between the two views as part of the rotation animation because a CoreAnimation block is automatically arranged around willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: and alpha is an animatable property.

Comment: There is no need to load both views. You can just load the appropriate view as needed, and unload it when no longer needed.